# generating a variable

Tags: stata

I am trying to  generate PMdist`i' variables, using the following codes

```
display "************** PM10 distances **************"


forval i=1/12599 {
    display "Attempting to compute distance `i'"

    capture geodist latitude longitude latitude`i' longitude`i' [if] [in], generate(PMdist`i')

    capture replace PMdist`i' = . if (PMdist`i' > 257 & !missing(PMdist`i'))

    capture drop latitude`i' longitude`i'
  }
egen PMmindist = rowmin(PMdist1-PMdist12581)

forval i=1/12599 {

    capture drop PMdist`i'
}
```

Can anyone tell me why its not working and what is the alternative solution?

Comment: I think this question is out of scope for this forum.  Needs to be related to economics.  Whats posted is computer code not related to econ.

Comment: @MikeJ actually according the help center: "Software questions: Questions related to software used in economics and econometrics, are on-topic here." Stata is used in economics - perhaps we should narrow the scope of site a bit (I would not be opposed to change it to 'software used in economics and econometrics applied to economic problem'  or something else that narrows it down - if you think it is good idea rise the issue on meta), but as our scope is defined now it is on-topic

Comment: @1muflon1  understood.   Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: How is it not working? What error are  you getting and at what line? What exactly is the problem? And what have you tried?